# Cesium Polygon entity get all positions and holes

Tags: javascript, cesium

I could not find a nice way to get the all **positions** and **holes** from Cesium polygon (*see the coordinates structure in attached image*), and as far as possible not to use recursive function to get all the coordinates. Also checked API and there is nothing that I can use, `ex. "getCoordiantes" or something like that`.

**Usage** to check all the coordinates height for comparing.

Here is also the GeoJSON example:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "dataType": "AirspaceType",
            "geometryExtension": {
                "extruded": {
                    "maxHeight": 10000,
                    "minHeight": 0
                }
            },
            "id": "d50b2df0-9447-4a27-8710-eb62dff66ade",
            "name": "Unnamed Layer",
            "category": "default"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0.2, 0, 0],
                    [0.2, 0.2, 0],
                    [0, 0.2, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]
                ],
                [
                    [0.03504, 0.096817],
                    [0.035384, 0.18917],
                    [0.18132, 0.18917],
                    [0.174109, 0.020599],
                    [0.03504, 0.096817]
                ],
                [
                    [0.059077, 0.100937],
                    [0.059077, 0.173034],
                    [0.157283, 0.173034],
                    [0.157283, 0.100937],
                    [0.059077, 0.100937]
                ],
                [
                    [0.07968, 0.154838],
                    [0.13153, 0.156555],
                    [0.136681, 0.124626],
                    [0.094102, 0.118446],
                    [0.07968, 0.154838]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

[image: Cesium structure for polygon]

Answer (score 0):

Use **myEntity.polygon.hierarchy.valueOf();**

See this working [Cesium Sandcastle example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=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)